# How to delete plain text in html

Tags: php, trim, strip-tags

Could someone help me to delete trim / delete plain text from html content?

for example; from this HTML:

```
lorem ipsum xxx lorem ipsum
orem ipsum yyy
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum zzz
<img src=ijustwantthisline.jpg>
<br/>
<img src=ijustwantthisline.jpg>
```

i just want to get the html lines; as like:

```
<img src=ijustwantthisline.jpg>
<br/>
<img src=ijustwantthisline.jpg>
```

as like strip_tags; i need strip_text etc...

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Please read this article and try to improve your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist Do you want to keep the text inside tags like `<p>keep this text?</p>`

Comment: What you are looking for are called textnodes.

Comment: i want to keep only img & br tags

Comment: how is that generated?

Answer (score 0):

This will find all the tags and then add them to $tags. As it only looks for tags, it won't match the plain text. $string was the string you provided and $tags is the html lines you wanted.

```
preg_match_all('/(<.*?>)/', $string, $matches);
$tags = implode($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty unclear. However there are pleanty of ways you can remove an element on a html page.

```
<?php
$html = "abc<p></p><p>dd</p><b>non-empty</b>"; 
$pattern = "/<p[^>]*><\\/p[^>]*>/"; 
//$pattern = "/<[^\/>]*>([\s]?)*<\/[^>]*>/";  use this pattern to remove any empty tag

echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $html); 
// output
//abc<p>dd</p><b>non-empty</b>
?>
```

If you can absolutely guarantee that there are no angle brackets in the HTML other than those used to open and close tags, this should work:

```
s%(>|\G)([^<]*?)($key)%$1$2<b>$3</b>%g
```